# ImportError: `save_model` requires h5py

Tags: windows, python-3.x, tensorflow, h5py

I have windows 10. I am using python 3.5 and the following dependencies:

- tensorflow==1.2.0
- numpy==1.14.2
- pandas==0.22.0
- h5py==2.7.1

I download the code from this link: [here](https://medium.com/@curiousily/credit-card-fraud-detection-using-autoencoders-in-keras-tensorflow-for-hackers-part-vii-20e0c85301bd)

I am running it but I faced the following problem: ImportError: `save_model` requires h5py.

I google it I found that I need to install these dependencies:

- List libhdf5
- List h5py

h5py was installed, but libhdf5 can't:
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libhdf5 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for libhdf5

Any help?

Comment: `pip install h5py` has always been enough for me.

Comment: Even I installed it, same errors !!

Comment: Try installing [libhdf5](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/release/obtain518.html). If it still doesn't work there is someone reporting that `pip install cython` solved the issue.